# Pass data from a service to widget via intents

Tags: android, android-widget

I've got a service which calls an intent to send a custom text to my AppWidgetProvider. For this I use the onRecieve method and check for the right action.

So I have two questions, the first one is, is this the right way and the second why is my onReceive method never get called?

I added the manifest this following part

```
<receiver android:label="KreativBarometer Widget"
   android:name=".widget.MyWidgetProvider" >
   <intent-filter >
      <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
   </intent-filter>
   <meta-data
       android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
       android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
 </receiver>
```

My AppWidgetProvider use the following onReceive method

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getAction().equals("APPWIDGET_UPDATE")){
        String text = intent.getStringExtra("newItemArrived");
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.TextView01, text);
    }
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
}
```

and for testing I use this intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent("APPWIDGET_UPDATE");
intent.putExtra("newItemArrived", "Neue Frage erschienen");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to modify your manifest file to include two things :

1. One more action in your `<receiver>` to indicate you have an intent coming into your widget
2. Register your service.

Perhaps this video would be useful : https://youtu.be/DJsNmS-PvD8?t=2m7s

Answer (score 0):

To pass custom date you need to use a Bundle as:

```
val intent = Intent(context, ItemsCollectionRemoteViewsService::class.java)
            .apply {
                val extrasBundle = Bundle()
                extrasBundle.putSerializable(WIDGET_DATA, widgetData)
                putExtra(WIDGET_Bundle_DATA, extrasBundle)
            }
        remoteViews.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.items_list_view, intent)
```